# Shapeless: Trying to restrict HList elements by their type

Tags: scala, constraints, shapeless, hlist

**Question 1 - Basic LUBConstraints**

My first try playing around with existing LUBConstraints fails for missing evidence (see code block below). Any hint why? Isn't an empty list a valid list of longs? no element violates the constraint.

```
import shapeless.ops.coproduct
import shapeless.{::, :+:, Coproduct, HNil, HList}

object testLUBConstraints {
  import shapeless.LUBConstraint._

  // !!! see comment on question - this satisfies the implicit below!!! 
  // implicit val hnilLUBForLong = new LUBConstraint[HNil.type, Long] {}

  def acceptLong[L <: HList : <<:[Long]#λ](l: L) = true
  val validLong = acceptLong(1l :: HNil)

  val validEmpty = acceptLong(HNil)
  //  => WHY??? Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type shapeless.LUBConstraint[shapeless.HNil.type,Long]
  //  MY EXPECTATION WAS: 'implicit def hnilLUB[T] = new LUBConstraint[HNil, T] {}' defined within LUBConstraint companion should provide so

  // val invalid = acceptLong(1.0d :: HNil) -> fails due to missing evidence (as expected)
}
```

Any help appreciated.

*Question 2 - Own Constraint using Coproduct*
(split into a seperate question: [Shapeless: own HList constraint using Coproduct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786247))

*Question 3 - restrict case classes by parameter types*
(split into a separat question: [Shapeless: restricting case class types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788780))

Comment: I managed to get around the first ERROR (in code block of _Question 1_) by locally declaring `implicit val hnilLUBForLong = new LUBConstraint[HNil.type, Long] {}` - It seems that the implicit value provided by the declared method doesn't exactly type match: `LUBConstraint[HNil, Long] =!= LUBConstraint[HNil.type, Long]`
Intention or even a bug?

Comment: working on the implicit resolution of CPConstraint (see _Question 2_)
Having `val hlLong: ::[Long, HNil] = 1L :: HNil` and implicitly looking up a CPConstraint for it with `implicit val cpcLong = implicitly[CPConstraint[hlLong.type, CPType]]` I tried `implicit val scpcEmptyLong1: CPConstraint[::[Long,HNil], CPType] = new CPConstraint[::[Long,HNil], CPType] {}`, which does **NOT** fit the implicit searched but `implicit val scpcEmptyLong2: CPConstraint[hlLong.type, CPType] = new CPConstraint[hlLong.type, CPType] {}` would. - WHY??? What's the difference?

Comment: This should probably be three separate questions. In the first case you can fix the issue by explicitly typing `HNil` as `HNil`: `acceptLong(HNil: HNil)` should compile.

Comment: ok - I will try to split the questions.

Comment: @TravisBrown - thanks, explicitly typing helps.

Comment: @TravisBrown Wouldn't a slightly more open declaration avoid an explicit typing: something like `implicit def hnilLUB[HN <: HNil, T] = new LUBConstraint[HN, T] {}` - would this be worth a proposal for improvement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inferred type of the value `HNil` will be the singleton type `HNil.type`, which is a proper subtype of `HNil`. Because type classes like `LUBConstraint` are invariant, any available instance for `HNil` won't be found if you're asking for an instance for `HNil.type`.

There's been [some discussion](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/78) of changing the definition of `HNil` so that this would work, but it's not trivial, and it's not clear that all the implications of the change are desirable. In the meantime you can write `HNil: HNil` to upcast the value.